# can I get the collections from robomongo to display it in a web page by nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to display all the databases and their respective collections and documents from mongoDB in NodeJS

Comment: have you tried any code yourself? Can you post the code you have tried / research you have tried to do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the [**`listDatabases()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#listdatabases) method:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {

    // Use the admin database for the operation
    var adminDb = db.admin();

    // List all the available databases
    adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);

        db.close();
    });
});
```

Collections can be listed with [**`collectionNames`**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html#list-existing-collections):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
        console.log(collections);
    });
});
```

You could also use **[MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/)** within node.js to expose the MongoDB-Native Object that will list all the databases and their respective collections

In node.js, install Mongoose as follows:

```
$ npm install mongoose
```

Now you can use the mongoose object to connect to MongoDB and map out all collections within the databases:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    url = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
    mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(error, names) {
        if (error) {
           throw new Error(error);
        } else {
            names.map(function(name) {
                console.log('found collection %s', name);
            });
        }
    });
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error){
    throw new Error(error);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
        Server = require('mongodb').Server

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
db.open(function (err, db) {
    var adminDb = db.admin();
    adminDb.listDatabases(function (err, dbs) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else console.log(dbs.databases);
        var data = dbs.databases;
        data.forEach(function (res) {
            if (res.name == "node_REST") {
                console.log(res);
            }
        })
        db.close();
    });
});
```